# L3G4200D Gyroscope not sending ACK

Tags: i2c, gyro

I am working on interfacing to a [L3G4200D Gyroscope breakout board](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1272) .

I am using it in I2C mode, and the microcontroller I use is the 8051 (via bit banging).

I havent connected anything to the SDO pin, so it is high by default.

My code is [here](https://github.com/khandharjay/Gyro-Code/blob/master/Lab4/src/gyro.c).

The problem is that I always get 0xFF, when I try to read anything from the gyro.

Any suggestions on the mistake I am making?

EDIT:: Solution
While reading from the Gyro,using I2C, it needs a repeated start signal. I did that and it worked.

Comment: Just a note on your code, the addresses you're using look correct but the comment next to them says DO=0. Thought I'd mention because at first glance I thought that was your problem and it might confuse a few others as well.

Comment: Are you getting an ACK bit from the slave? Your code doesn't seem to check, but you could check otherwise (e.g. with an oscilloscope).

Comment: It's probably inconsequential, but your `in()` function (found in [eeprom.c](https://github.com/khandharjay/Gyro-Code/blob/master/Lab4/src/eeprom.c)) only generates 8 clocks per byte instead of 9. Incoming bytes have ACK bits, too. Is this code known to work with other devices?

Comment: How about a schematic? Do you have CS held high (required for I2C)? Also, with a quick skim of the datasheet, I don't see that SDO is high by default; I'd add a pull-up. As fm_andreas asked, are you getting an ACK from the slave?

Comment: I am not getting a ACK signal from the Gyroscope. For the ACK signal, the gyro has to put a low level on the SDA line, but it keeps it high always.
Also the SDO line for this breakout is high by default(I verfied it with a multimeter too)

Comment: My I2C code has worked previously with a I2C EEPROM and a I2C I/O Expander.

Comment: @DoxyLover--Yes the CS is held high.